# WPF DragMove action only works when there's a background

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent

My grid

```
<Grid MouseDown="DragTitle">
  <Border></Border>
</Grid>
```

The event only seems to work if the grid has a background, and targets the border inside. Why is this? Is there something that I'm missing with the Grid Element, maybe something like `display:block` in CSS?

Comment: what do you mean by "targets the border inside"?

Comment: The event works on the border itself. Which really is the opposite of what I am trying to do, but trying to figure out the issue with grid on handling this event when background is applied